# Can not assign variable because type is null?

Tags: javascript

`canvas.getActiveObject().type` returns the type of the currently active element in the canvas.

```
var type = canvas.getActiveObject().type;
if(type){
     console.log(type);
}
```

But when no element is active, I get TypeError, which of course happens because no element is active so there is nothing to getActiveObject from.

> TypeError: canvas.getActiveObject(...) is null

Why can't I assign a variable when the `activeObject` is `null`?

Same error happens, when I try

```
var type = '';
if(canvas.getActiveObject().type){
    type = canvas.getActiveObject().type
}
```

Comment: that's not what's wrong. The error is fairly clear: `canvas.getActiveObject()` gives you back a `null`. There is no active object. So you can't ask for `canvas.getActiveObject().type`, because that's equivalent of asking for `null.type` and that's impossible: `null` has no properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`canvas.getActiveObject()` is returning `null`.

That means that `canvas.getActiveObject().type` is the same as `null.type`.

Referencing any member of `null` will throw an exception.

You can solve this any number of ways

Three lines of code:

```
let type = '';
if(canvas.getActiveObject()) {
    type = canvas.getActiveObject().type;
}
```

Or a one-liner:

```
let type = canvas.getActiveObject()
   ? canvas.getActiveObject().type
   : '';
```

Or a more compact one-liner:

```
let type = (canvas.getActiveObject() || { type: ''}).type;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a null value like an object, I think you should safely access the value like.

```js
var type = '';
if(canvas.getActiveObject() && canvas.getActiveObject().type){
    type = canvas.getActiveObject().type
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to access the property `type` returned by the function `getActiveObject()`, but since the function returns `null`, accessing the `type` property is throwing an error. What you need to do instead is check the return value of `getActiveObject()` before trying to access any of its members.

The snippet below, which is based on your code, instead checks that the active object returned is not null before attempting to access the members that reside within it.

```
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
if (activeObject) {
     console.log(activeObject.type);
}
```